# Can I take only certain keys from each config file?

Tags: python, fb-hydra

Let's say I have two config files in the "base" directory, "base/v1.yaml" and "base/v2.yaml". Let's say each of these are structured something like:

```
model:
  embedding_size: 20
  num_layers: 4
  ...

dataset:
  name: ...
```

If I have a new yaml and am trying to set defaults, is there a way I can choose to only take e.g. "model" from v1, and then "dataset" from v2? Ideally, something like:

```
defaults:
  - base/v1.model
  - base/v2.dataset
  - _self_

...
```

Comment: This question is not good. To write a good understandible question with a [mcve], I recommend reading [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly what you are asking for but you can load both and save the relevant parts in a separate field e.g.:

```
defaults:
 - v1@base/v1
 - v2@base/v2
 - _self_

model: ${v1.model}
dataset: ${v2.dataset}
```

the `v1@base/v1` syntax stores the contents of `base/v1.yaml` in a field called `v1`

the `${}` is used for value interpolation

Comment: Thanks, that's really useful. The only issue is that if I have a defaults list in base/v1 or base/v2 (taking defaults from another file), the default values don't get carried over. Is there a way to get this to work too?

Comment: if I am understanding this correctly, you should be able to give a name with the "name@file" in the defaults list of "base/v1.yaml" and then access it with v1.name in your main yaml file

Answer (score 0):

> If I have a new yaml and am trying to set defaults, is there a way I can choose to only take e.g. "model" from v1, and then "dataset" from v2?

No.
You will have to restructure your config, disentangling them into two config groups (e.g. model and dataset).